# Java: Appended string need to remove certain parts

Tags: java

I would like to know i wish to remove appended strings previously how can i do that.

```
  Example                        getValue() value is
  --------------------------     ------------------------
  information1.getValue()         Test A </n>abc = 1234
  information2.getValue()         Test A </n>def = Test B
  information3.getValue()         123 </n>jkl = Test B
  information4.getValue()         123 </n>abc = Test A
```

Expected output i should get is

```
  Output
  -------
  abc
  def
  jkl
  abc
```

whereby i should ignore characters before < /n> and characters after =

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.println(information1.getValue().substring(
    information1.getValue().indexOf(">")+1,
    information1.getValue().indexOf("=")).trim());
```

Use Below link to see example

> https://repl.it/repls/AmazingSmoothAnalyst

**Using StringBuffer**

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(information1.getValue());
      sb.delete(0,sb.indexOf(">")+1).delete(sb.indexOf("=")-1,sb.length()); 
      System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: I would just add that you'll also get the " " space before the =. You could strip away spaces if this is a problem.

Comment: use trim() function

Comment: thanks dis is a good approach . can we use delete function as i saw there is delete (from,to) so there will be 2 times the delete function appear which is 1 for front part before > and another for back part after =. as there might be some cases need check where to trim like 
if >does not exist then need delete for words after = or
if = does not exist need delete for words before >
if > and = exist then need delete for words before > and after =
and the word abc can also be a>bc

Comment: we can but delete() doesn't work for string because The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a String object cannot be changed. If there is a necessity to make a lot of modifications to Strings of characters, then you should use String Buffer & String Builder Classes.

Comment: if i use string builder and buffer can share what solution can be done as i kind of confuse. u can add on top of yours. really thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*<\\n>([^ ]*). =. *");
String replaced = p.matcher(s.getValue()).group(1));
```

Comment: thanks let me check if have <a</n>bc,what will hapeen

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex to capture words, lookahead `(?<=)` and lookbehind `(?=)` tokens can capture words

```
String regx="(?<=</n>)(.*)(?==)";
Pattern datePatt = Pattern.compile(regx);
Matcher m = datePatt.matcher("Test A </n>abc = 1234");
System.out.println("checking");
if(m.find()){
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
abc
```

Comment: thanks let me check if have <a</n>bc,what will hapeen